# select date where year and month between certain period with Query builder Yii

Tags: php, yii, query-builder

I want to select data from database where date field is between certain period. For example: between January 2015 and April 2015.

```
$Q1 = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
                ->select('count(kode_lelang) as totTender')
                ->from('proc_lelang')
                ->where('year(waktu_mulai)='.$year and 'month(waktu_mulai) between 1 and 4')
                ->queryAll();
```

But I do not think that I am writing the right syntax. so, Please help me.

Comment: Whats the output of that query? Why do you think the syntax is not right? Is there an error message?

Comment: I need to select data per 4 months. So I select data where period between January and April, May and August, Semtember and Desember. And they give me the same result. I think that impossible happen in my data.

Comment: What about case like this: December 2015 and February 2016?

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is that the 'and' is not inside the string:

```
$Q1 = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
                ->select('count(kode_lelang) as totTender')
                ->from('proc_lelang')
                ->where('year(waktu_mulai)='{$year}' and month(waktu_mulai) between 1 and 4')
                ->queryAll();
```

Comment: @Diyah Please consider accepting and possibly upvoting Victor's answer if you found it helpful.  It's the best way to say *thanks* around here.

Answer (score 0):

There is a misplaced quote in your *where* statement.  It's simpler to use double quotes and variable replacement instead.

```
->where("year(waktu_mulai)={$year} and month(waktu_mulai) between 1 and 4")
```

Please not that this is dangerous if the user can control the content of variable `$year` as this could lead to SQL injections.  Check the Yii docs on how to prevent SQL injections.